# Are minimongoid hooks done server side?

Tags: meteor

I'm using minimongoid on my meteor project and I  don't know if before Create and validations are done server side or client. Does anyone know ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From its `package.js` file it looks like both! Also mentioned in the github readme.

So you can share the model files between the client and server. I'm not absolutely certain however that if you insert a model on the client and its been fiddled with by a hacker or something that it will be validated on the server automagically.

You might have to also validate it on the server too. The best place to do this would be in your collection's `.allow` method. Looking at the source of minimongoid there isn't anything tied up to `.allow` or `.deny` so you will need to validate it on the server with these.

Comment: Well I'll try with a deny. Thanks.
But I still think those should be verified server side directly in minimongoid...